# What does this error symbol on the EV3 mean?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

I get this error image pop up when I power on my EV3. What does it mean?

[image]

Also, is there a list of different error codes anywhere, I looked in the User Manual and I could not see anything.

Cheers!

Comment: Educated guess: is the storage on the EV3 brick itself full by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

The hard disk is likely full on the brick. Try deleting some projects to allocate space.